# Firebase Geofire centre map on location from database

Tags: swift, firebase, coordinates, geofire

So I have multiple locations stored in my database, using Geofire. I want to centre the map on a specific one.

I want to know if it is possible to access the firebase database to only retrieve the coordinates saved by GeoFire as a variable so that I can create a CLLocation and centre the map on this one location. Here is my code.

I call `getJobLocation` in my `viewDidLoad`. This is where I want to grab the job coordinates from Firebase and then call the other methods i.e. `showJobsOnMap` using these coordinates

```
func getJobLocation(jobID: String) {
   ...
}

func centreMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {

    let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, 2000, 2000)
    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    let annoIdentifier = "job"
    var annotationView: MKAnnotationView?

    if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self) {

        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "User")
        annotationView?.image = UIImage(named:"currentLocationPin")
    } else if let deqAnno = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "job") {
        annotationView = deqAnno
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    } else {
        let MKAV = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annoIdentifier)
        MKAV.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        annotationView = MKAV
    }

    if let annotationView = annotationView, let _ = annotation as? JobAnnotation {
        let postsRef = self.dataBaseRef.child("jobs")
        postsRef.observe(.value, with: { (posts) in
            for _ in posts.children {
                annotationView.canShowCallout = true
                annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
                annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "jobPin")
            }
        })
    }

    return annotationView
}

func showJobsOnMap(location: CLLocation) {
    let circleQuery = geoFire!.query(at: location, withRadius: 2.5)
    _ = circleQuery?.observe(GFEventType.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in
        if let key = key, let location = location {

            if key == self.job.postID {
                let postsRef = self.dataBaseRef.child("jobs").child(key)
                postsRef.observe(.value, with: { (posts) in
                    for _ in posts.children {

                        let post = Post(snapshot: posts )
                        let jobDate = post.postDateTime
                        let price = post.price
                        let anno = JobAnnotation(coordinate: location.coordinate, jobID: key, jobDate: jobDate, title: "£\(price) - \(jobDate)")
                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(anno)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me? Why you are not using Google Map?Why Apple Map View. Because you can easily achieve this task in Google Map.

Comment: I'l try it out, cheers